# Mysql request - get contacts

Tags: mysql, request

**I have a contacts table:**

```
from_user_id   to_user_id
300            301
301            298
```

I'm trying to find all unique contacts for user_id = 301. For this user it will be: 300 and 298;

I have tried this request but I have wrong results:

```
SELECT 
    u.name,
    IF(c.from_user_id = '.(int)$user->id.', c.from_user_id, c.to_user_id) AS uid
FROM 
    `#__contacts`   AS c
LEFT JOIN 
    `#__users`  
AS 
    u   
ON
    uid = u.id
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: See if you can solve it with UNION. Keep it really simple

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM `#__contacts` AS c
LEFT JOIN `#__users` AS u ON c.to_user_id = u.id
WHERE '.(int)$user->id.' IN (c.from_user_id, c.to_user_id)
ORDER BY c.created DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but this doesn't work. I think problem is in c.to_user_id = u.id